# Is it possible to add DiplayManager and Display class implementation in Android API level 16 or below?

Tags: android, api, presentation

Android API level has added few APIs like DisplayManager, Presentation etc in API level17.
Is it possible to develop an app using API level 16 which achieves the same functionality as we do in API level 17 using Presentation APIs?

Or Is there any way I can implement Presentation class myself in my Android App with API level 16 or below??

Thanks,
Smitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code (ttps://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Presentation.java), i'd say you can include Presentation pretty easily in your app, but you'll have to remove the DisplayManager-related functionnalities. (which probably kind of defeats the purpose)

DisplayManager is probably much more complex to integrate, as it depends on other classes, some of which are hidden.